# Micrometer timer metrics not displayed in Cloudwatch when @Timed is used

Tags: spring-boot, amazon-cloudwatch, spring-micrometer

I am trying to send my API application metrics to AWS Cloudwatch using the mircometer registry's timer. I have successfully managed to send custom metrics by implementing it manually so far. But, I want to send the metrics using the @Timed annotation, and it doesn't work. Here are the things I have tried so far:

```
@Timed("test")
@RestController
public class TempHandler{

    @GetMapping(value="/path")
    @Timed(value="ping")
    public ResponseEntity ping(@RequestHeader Map<String,String> headers){
        return applyHeaders(Response.status(200).entity("ok"));
    }
}
```

I have created a @Configuration class as well to return a TimedAspect object.

```
@Configuration
public class TimedConfiguration {
   @Bean
   public TimedAspect timedAspect(MeterRegistry registry) {
      return new TimedAspect(registry);
   }
}
```

I have included the spring AOP dependancy in my build.gradle as well. Please help me to figure out what I am doing wrong. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I believe the only problem is the Configuration class (we have to give Cloudwatch reference to Meter Registry), which actually required some configuration. Here is an example of it that is working for me:

```
    @Configuration
    public class MetricsConfig {

    @Value("${amazon.aws.accesskey}")
    private String amazonAWSAccessKey;

    @Value("${amazon.aws.secretkey}")
    private String amazonAWSSecretKey;

    @Value("${amazon.aws.region}")
    private String region;

    @Value("${management.metrics.export.cloudwatch.namespace}")
    private String matricsNamespace;

    @Value("${management.metrics.export.cloudwatch.duration-in-min}")
    private Integer durationInMin;

    @Bean
    public CloudWatchAsyncClient cloudWatchAsyncClient() {
        return CloudWatchAsyncClient
            .builder()
            .region(Region.of(region))
            .credentialsProvider(new AwsCredentialsProvider() {
                @Override
                public AwsCredentials resolveCredentials() {
                    AwsCredentials awsCredentials = new AwsCredentials() {
                        @Override
                        public String accessKeyId() {
                            return amazonAWSAccessKey;
                        }

                        @Override
                        public String secretAccessKey() {
                            return amazonAWSSecretKey;
                        }
                    };
                    return awsCredentials;
                };
            })
            .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public MeterRegistry getMeterRegistry() {
        CloudWatchConfig cloudWatchConfig = setupCloudWatchConfig();

        CloudWatchMeterRegistry cloudWatchMeterRegistry =
            new CloudWatchMeterRegistry(
                cloudWatchConfig,
                Clock.SYSTEM,
                cloudWatchAsyncClient());
    
    // If you want some internal metrices you as per your requirement else remove these.    
        new JvmMemoryMetrics().bindTo(cloudWatchMeterRegistry);
        new JvmGcMetrics().bindTo(cloudWatchMeterRegistry);
        new JvmHeapPressureMetrics().bindTo(cloudWatchMeterRegistry);
        new JvmInfoMetrics().bindTo(cloudWatchMeterRegistry);
        new FileDescriptorMetrics().bindTo(cloudWatchMeterRegistry);
        new UptimeMetrics().bindTo(cloudWatchMeterRegistry);
        new ProcessorMetrics().bindTo(cloudWatchMeterRegistry);
        new DiskSpaceMetrics(new File(".")).bindTo(cloudWatchMeterRegistry);

        return cloudWatchMeterRegistry;
    }

    private CloudWatchConfig setupCloudWatchConfig() {
        CloudWatchConfig cloudWatchConfig = new CloudWatchConfig() {

            private Map<String, String> configuration = Map.of(
                "cloudwatch.namespace", matricsNamespace,
                "cloudwatch.step", Duration.ofMinutes(durationInMin).toString());

            @Override
            public String get(String key) {
                return configuration.get(key);
            }
        };
        return cloudWatchConfig;
    }


    @Bean
    public TimedAspect timedAspect(MeterRegistry registry) {
        return new TimedAspect(registry);
    }

   }
```

I hope you have added these two dependencies as well.

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
        <artifactId>micrometer-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.0</version>
    </dependency>   
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
        <artifactId>micrometer-registry-cloudwatch2</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Regards